# The joystick movement in the First Person View is too fast in the Forge modelViewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

1. The joystick movement in the First Person View is too fast in the Forge modelViewer. How can we adjust it?
2. The average size of our 3D models is 20-30 MB. Even with a good internet speed, these take around 15-30 secs to load models in Forge viewer. Any recommendations for reducing the loading time of model?

Answer (score 0):

**Re: The joystick movement in the First Person View is too fast in the Forge modelViewer. How can we adjust it?**

click ctrl and + , or ctrl and - to adjust the walking speed. An instant message will show up in the top to indicate how much the speed is (see attached snapshot)

**Re: The average size of our 3D models is 20-30 MB. Even with a good internet speed, these take around 15-30 secs to load models in Forge viewer. Any recommendations for reducing the loading time of the models?**

Are you using SVF or SVF2? if SVF, it is definitely worth to give it a try with SVF2, which may have better performance.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/svf2-public-beta-new-optimized-viewer-format
In addition, model size is not an absolute flag with model loading. The model loading depends on how much the translated data and how complex the data are.